# Import Error regarding statsmodels in python

Tags: python-3.x, pip, seaborn, statsmodels

I have installed the `statsmodels` package through `pip`, because I want to use the `seaborn` package for plotting cdfs of distributions. So, when I try to run this:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

normal_numbers = np.random.normal(size=100)
sns.distplot(normal_numbers, hist_kws={'cumulative': True}, kde_kws={"cumulative": True})
```

I get the 
`ImportError: Cumulative distributions are currentlyonly implemented in statsmodels.Please install statsmodels.`

If I remove the `kde_kws` argument everything works fine, but I don't know why it doesn't work with the `kde_kws`.

However, using the ananconda environment, everything seems to be ok even using the `kde_kws` with the expected behaviour.

---

**Edit 1**: seaborn version == 0.9.0
     statsmodel version == 0.9.0

If I `import statsmodels.nonparametric.api as smnp` I get the error:

`ImportError: cannot import name 'factorial' from 'scipy.misc' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/misc/__init__.py)`

---

**Edit 2**: After uninstalling the seaborn 0.9.0 version and installing the 0.10.0rc2 version, everything seems to work fine.

Comment: You haven't installed statsmodels in the environment where you run this code.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest When I do `pip install` all of the packages are installed under the same directory. I can verify that when I go to the jupyter environment, import the libraries and get their actual path.

Comment: You can test with `import statsmodels` whether it's installed or not.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes, it's there; the statsmodels package is imported without any error being thrown.

Comment: Did you maybe just forget to restart the kernel after installing?

Comment: No, I've tried everything. On windows and mac, exactly same behaviour.

Comment: Weird. Which seaborn and which statsmodel version is this? What happens when you do `import statsmodels.nonparametric.api as smnp`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Ok, thanks! Solved it (maybe temporarily).